# how to fix "OperationError: no such table"

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

## I am creating a database for machines at my workplace for the once that have been sold and the once available

## using sqlite3 on my jupyter notebook i created a database file roots.db

```
`import sqlite3

def create_rdb():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("roots.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roots_store (id INTEGER 
    PRIMARY KEY,make TEXT,machine TEXT,model TEXT,s_n TEXT,end_user 
    TEXT,status TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(make,machine,model,s_n,end_user,status):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("roots.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO roots_store VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
    (make,machine,model,s_n,end_user,status)) 
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

insert('Atlas Copco','Air Compressor','GA200','AP34582','Dangote 
     Refinery','Sold')

def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("roots.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM roots_store')
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

connect()
print(view())`
```

its suppose to store the details using the insert function in the database and ill view it with the printview function, instead its giving me an

```
`OperationalError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3e5cdcdeeab3> in <module>
     15     conn.close()
     16 
---> 17 insert('Atlas Copco','Air Compressor','GA200','AP34582','Dangote 
Refinery','Sold')
     18 
     19 def view():

<ipython-input-2-3e5cdcdeeab3> in insert(make, machine, model, s_n, 
end_user, status)
     11     conn = sqlite3.connect("roots.db")
     12     cur = conn.cursor()
---> 13     cur.execute("INSERT INTO roots_store VALUES 
 (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
 (make,machine,model,s_n,end_user,status))
     14     conn.commit()
     15     conn.close()`
```

Comment: where are you calling create_rdb() function?

Comment: did'nt know had to, i thought the file present in the argument was the way to go